# Desktop app - Hibernate (using JPA EntityManager) / Spring / Swing -driven extended session

Tags: java, spring, swing, hibernate, jpa

I'm having trouble extending a JPA persistence context, a la "open-session-in-conversation" pattern, for a Swing two-tier Java SE desktop app that I am working on.

The benefits of this for me would be:

- Lazy loading objects to the GUI
- Allowing the user to edit / work with objects without having to reload them from the database- in case of edits by other users. This would be checked by Hibernate's versioning and an error would be thrown if the persistence context lasted the duration of the 'conversation'

There are lots of approaches detailed for web use, but hardly anything out there for desktop use.

Can anyone suggest a suitable approach?

Comment: I use 'open-session-in-window' pattern, when every dialog window has its own hibernate session. It was long time ago, with Hibernate 2.x, and does not very well. Especially when some Exception was thrown. All hibernate objects in session becomes invalid and you had to fix exception cause and repeat all changes.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking is the way to go. Can I ask if you have changed your approach since?

Comment: Unfortunately, i was my first and last desktop application. But it work pretty fast, maybe because we have not so many users, and each user costs one connection to DB, so if you have 100-200 users, that approach can be dangerous. And StaleException very painful, we deal with it by writing merge window, where show to user diff between his and server versions.